# Federation server installer

Tags: federation

I am trying to figure out how to install/set up federation server, but when I go here https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/services/federation and click on the prebuilt binaries link it will take me on here
https://github.com/stellar/go/releases
But there is no installer for federation server, am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately since stellar uses a monorepo now (different services in the same git repository) the releases page is filled with other services and you have to go to the next page to find the latest Federation Server release, which is here: https://github.com/stellar/go/releases/tag/federation-v0.2.0